# Assigning grades to a vector based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have two vectors

```
vThresholds = as.vector(c(0.12, 0.34, 0.56, 0.85)) 
vCandidates = as.vector(rnorm(100))
```

I want to assign grades to the candidates based on where they lie in vThresholds. I wrote a function as follows

```
fGrades = function (x, y) {
  if(y <= x[1]){
    grade = "A"
  } else if(y > x[1] & y <= x[2]){
    grade = "B"
  } else if(y > x[2] & y <= x[3]){
    grade = "C"
  } else if(y > x[3] & y <= x[4]){
    grade = "D"
  }else {grade = "E"}
  grade
}
```

However, when I use

```
mapply(fGrades, vThresholds, vCandidates)
```

I get an error

```
Error in if (y <= x[1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

On tracing this error I find that mapply coverts x into NA.

I can get around this problem by looping through vCandidates. However, I am looking for a vectorized version of this solution. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something more like this...?

```
 LETTERS[1:5][findInterval(vCandidates,vThresholds)+1]
```

Side note: the `as.vector` isn't necessary.

Be sure to read `?findInterval` carefully to make sure you're getting the behavior that you want on the boundaries of the intervals.

A short explanation of the error you got:

It's not so much that `mapply` is converting anything, but that you asked for an element of `x` that doesn't exist. `mapply` sends only a single value to the function `fGrades` for each of `x` and `y`. So when inside that function you ask for `x[2]`, R returns `NA`, since in that context `x` has length of only 1.

Comment: I thought giving me the check and then switching to joran was _just_ right. Showed you got both messages but went with the better one.

Answer (score 1):

Should have used: `sapply( vCandidates, fGrades, x=vThresholds)`.

Although I think @joran's `findInterval` coding is better, but there is also the task of helping you understand the R `*apply`-functions' behaviors and proper applications. You didn't really want a 1-1 pairing of vCandidates with vThresholds which is what `mapply` provides. This `sapply` call uses vThresholds as a fixed `x=` argument, so it is available to function:`fGrades` during the calculations.